# mysterious right margin on 100% height/width web page

Tags: html, css, margin

I am in the process of making an offline SPA. Even though I have set both `html` and `body` to `100%` there is a mysterious margin on the right side of the page that is causing the horizontal scrollbar to appear. I have tried to debug but get practically no useful information, except that the FF debugger highlights this margin as in the `<html>` tag. I have uploaded the site [here](http://preahkumpii.com/test-site/index.html). Please remember that loading will take a while, b/c it is intended to be packaged for offline use. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The horizontal scrollbar is being caused by the `width:100%` and/or the `padding: 0 20px` on the input box in the upper right corner.

Roughly line 94 in the CSS file.

Comment: a small explanation: padding adds to the width of a element, while margin does not. This is known as the "box model", http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html